# Two elements, make one overflow hidden while the other registers scroll for both elements?

Tags: android, jquery, css

This is mainly for handheld touch devices.

I'm using the jQuery library and Hammer.js to register touch events.

I have 2 elements, one sidebar and one content. The content is layered over the top of the menu and you swipe right over the content to reveal the sidebar.

When you swipe the content, I apply `overflow:hidden;`, making scrolling vertically only possible when over the sidebar.

Right now trying to scroll over the content does nothing, but I want to transfer the scrolling events over to the sidebar.

So when someone tries to scroll over the content, the sidebar moves instead, comprende?

Right now this is the function I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
     var hammertime = Hammer(element, {
        swipe_velocity: 0.1
    }).on('swiperight',function(){
         $(this).addClass('slidein');
    }).on('swipeleft',function(){
         $(this).removeClass('slidein');
    });;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the job, you have to use hammer.js, grab the deltaY position and use it in the sidebars .scrollTop position.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
     var posX=0, posY=0;
     var hammertime = Hammer(element, {
        drag: true,
        swipe_velocity: 0.1,
        drag_block_vertical:true
    }).on('swiperight',function(){
         $(this).addClass('slidein');
    }).on('swipeleft',function(){
         $(this).removeClass('slidein');
    }).on('drag',function(ev){
         posX = ev.gesture.deltaX;
         posY = ev.gesture.deltaY;
         $('.snap-drawer').scrollTop(posY);
    });
});
```